# what is the use of public/packages directory in laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I am little bit confusing with public/asset directory and public/package directory, which directory is prefered to add jquery third party plugin

Comment: Details better your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public/asset` contains your own application's assets, while `public/package` contains 3rd party and \ or packages' assets.

Sources:

1. https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure
2. https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages